# EATING DISORDER ALERT: Should I keep cutting or increase calories and allow more food freedom as a maintenance goal?

Tags: diet, body-fat, eating-habits, cutting

I'm 24, pretty active female (workout 6x a week and cardio 4x a week... spinning, power jump class and stair machine) and I'm 12,5% body fat by the caliper (5,2ft, 119lb... total 15lb of it being body fat).

I went throught a terrible phase when I bordered an eating disorder last year. I dropped to 110lb, lost my period and muscle mass, couldn't barely stay awake and be a functional human being. I never purged but I was eating 1200kcal a day and compensating with exercise. I've been coached by a therapist and behavioral nutritionist since then.

I did a mini cut in july, lost 300g of fat (and double the muscle mass..) and went abroad for a well deserved vacay in NYC for 2 weeks, having this 'spare room' to gain some fat there. I ate 4k calories per day, no exercise except walking. Truly enjoyed myself and glad I'm recovering.

Gained 2lb of fat in 2 weeks. It's 45 days since I returned and I've been following a super soft cutting diet my nutriotinist prescribed me not to compensate for stuff. I only lost 700g of that 2lb. There is still 300g to lose but I'm FED UP with the diet mentality and I want to be free from this burden.

She told me since I'm 12,5% body fat, it's time to end the cut and increase the calories again slowly. She increased like 100 calories of protein daily and told me I can go out for food twice on the weekends if I feel like it (it's hard for me not to, I'm highly social and me and my bf are foodies)

Should I insist on the cut or just do as she says and free myself?
I'm really scared to gain weight again, especially not having lost all the lbs I wanted to

Comment: This is not a question for strangers on the internet to answer. Since you are no pro, 12.5% body fat is very low for a woman, 20% is what most people would consider lean (and perhaps attractive, but that's subjective, maybe 20-25?), but we don't know your goals, history, mental issues and so on. Please consider seeking out someone you know and trust and that can help you out if you run into trouble.

Comment: It's a question for the internet if I am ok with sharing the story, which I am comfortable with. I guess attractiveness isn't in discussion at this topic, also. I prefer myself with 12% body fat. I just need advice on the fitness aspect of dieting. I am already being coached by professionals

Comment: Actually, @Raditz_35 is correct. This is something that you need to work with nutrition and possibly mental health professionals to accomplish. One thing that is common with eating disorders is body dysmorphia, This is not something for amateur hour.

Comment: 12% is indeed too low for a woman (looks bad too IMO). The caliper test is pretty unreliable BTW. There are YT videos comparing different methods, if you're interested (they are all unreliable, but some more so)

Answer (score 1):

You say you have another 300 grams you want to lose. How would you even measure that?

Weight fluctuates by time of day, bowel contents, levels of hydration etc.

I think you are looking at it too strict. You say you are "FED UP with the diet mentality", so let it go. Take the advice of the professional who is trying to help you.

Comment: I know it's 300g because I got measured with a professional in a clinic. It doesn't take fluids in account. Yeah maybe this amount of body fat is really hard for a person with a common life and social life to maintain?